# unable to save data when a user is logged in or using session in laravel

Tags: laravel, e-commerce

I have an eCommerce project whereby a user adds his product to cart whether they are logged in or not..when they are logged in their user_id is saved on the database and when they arent, the session_id is saved for the and the user_id is saved as zero...I want to achieve this, for the user to proceed to the checkout page they have to log in or create an account. this works perfectly for the users who added products to the cart when they were logged in but for the users who logged in at the cart section, at the checkout page the products in the cart disappear. how can I show the products in the checkout using the sesssion_id.

here is my checkout method in the controller that displays the cart products

```
public function checkout(){
        $events=Events::latest()->take(4)->get();
        $delivaddresses=shipping_charge::all();
        $usercartitems=Cart::usercartitems();
        return view('frontend.product.checkout')->with(compact('events','usercartitems','delivaddresses'));
    }
```

the usercartitems method in the cart model

```
public static function usercartitems(){
        if(Auth::check())
        {
            
            $usercartitems=Cart::with(['product'=>function($query){
                $query->select('id','merch_name','merch_image','merch_code');
            }])->where('user_id',Auth::id())->orderby('id','desc')->get();
        }else{
            $usercartitems=Cart::with(['product'=>function($query){
                $query->select('id','merch_name','merch_image','merch_code');
            }])->where('session_id',Session::get('session_id'))->orderby('id','desc')->get();
        }
        return  $usercartitems;
    }
```

Comment: As soon as a User logs in you will have to check if the session user has items in the cart, if there are items you will have to add the user id to this cart. So some carts will have a user_id and session_id

Comment: @Aless55 exactly that's what a trying to achieve such that to proceed to the checkout the user cart details will be displayed at the checkout using the session...have a look at the question i have reedited it

Comment: @Aless55 how can i code such a function..